# Using memcached in Rails app with Single Table Inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, single-table-inheritance

I have a Rails app that uses STI to handle different types of Users, such as:

```
class Admin < User
  ...
end
```

I want to use memcached, but I keep getting the dreaded "unknown class/module" error. I've tried pre-loading *all* of my ActiveRecord models to no avail. The first request works as normal, but the first pull from memcached errors out. I've followed [these instructions](http://casey0.com/archive/2007/January/cached_model_and_single_table_inheritance.html) to no avail either.

Is using memcached possible with single table inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) of the classes. When you call it from memcached the class definition isn't loaded, and then you get the error.

The workaround I use is:

```
Admin #lazily load the class definition

# do whatever that has cached Admins
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that restful_authentication's login_from_session method was being loaded before the aforementioned before_filter was run. Pre-loading the STI user classes at the top of this method worked.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick comment, i've read that using require_dependency 'admin' is preferred now, not sure why

```
require_dependency 'region'
```

Also, I've found that this is unnecessary if you add

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

to your production.rb (or development.rb for testing), this seems to catch all the models for caching